# Customizing x-axis MS C# Chart labels for MS Chart

Tags: winforms, charts

I am trying to label on the x-Axis each data point of BarChart. Right now as you see in the attached picture only 4 Bar are labelled (4/1/2012, 7/1/2012, 10/1/2012, 1/12013). I played with the "interval" attribute of the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis, but for no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the Interval on the `LabelStyle` instead of the axis directly.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
```